# What can I think of the function $F$ that's being used for most(?) explicit first order ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Almost *anything* on this topic only deals with how to *solve* ODEs, but so far I couldn't find one single site defining this ominous $F$ that's being used so often, like in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#General_definition_of_an_ODE) or in my script (not English, so I'll rather quote it instead of linking):

First of all F is introduced without definition as $F(y)=y'$ for a given vector y; it is then used like $F(t_0, y(t_0))=y'(t_0)$ which looks like a somewhat redundant use of arguments to me.

Things start to get confusing when $y_j=hF(t_{j-1},hy_{j-1})$ (where $h$ is the distance between any two adjacent $t_i$ and $y_i$ is the $i$th point computed by the Euler method) and they get even more confusing when

$$y''(t)=F'(t)=\frac{\Delta F}{\Delta t}(t,(y(t))+\frac{\Delta F}{\Delta y}(t,(y(t))F(t,(y(t))$$ (what is the $F(t,(y(t))$ doing here?)

and $F(t+\frac{h}{2}, y+\frac{h}{2}F(t,y))$ (this term came up like 2 lines later when we suddenly dealt with the Runge-Kutta-method)

I'm really having difficulties with the last two equations because I have no idea what to think of this $F$ and thus don't know what it is going to output when given a linear approximation (like in the latter equation).

Comment: In the wikipedia link $F$ is any function from a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ to whatever the codomain of $y$ is.

Comment: That still leaves me without a clue what the last term (and others) means though, isn't there any intuitive explanation what the single arguments are for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An explicit  first-order ODE is an equation of the form $y'=F(t,y)$ where $F$ is some (known) function. For example, if the ODE is $y'=y^2-2ty+e^t$, then we write $F(t,y)=y^2-2ty+e^t$.

To solve this ODE means to find a function $y$ of variable $t$ such that $$y'(t) = F(t,y(t))\quad \text{for all } t$$
*What is $y(t)$ doing here?* It's the second argument of $F$, by the design of this ODE. What else would you put as the second argument of $F$?

When we try to solve this equation numerically, the variable $t$ runs through a discrete set of values $t_j$, and we look for $y_j$, approximate value of $y$ at $t_j$. A crude method is to pretend $F(t,y(t))$ is constant on the interval $[t_j,t{j+1}]$, so that 
$$y_{j+1}=y_j+hF(t_j,y_j) $$
This isn't very precise, so a more sophisticated method is introduced, which takes the rate of change of $F$ into account. Being a function of two variables, $F$ responds to the changes of $t$, and also to the changes of $y$. This is accounted for by $\frac{\Delta F}{\Delta t}$
and $\frac{\Delta F}{\Delta y} F$

---

> I'm really having difficulties with the last two equations

Equations are not supposed to make  sense. Unless they are framed by sentences that express the mathematical reasoning behind those equations. Are there any such sentences in the book? Did the professor say anything at all while writing those formulas? I hope yes. Those would be the clues to understanding.

Comment: Thank you very much! Finally I have an idea of what $F$ looks like! The last equation makes perfectly sense now and the second last the problem reduced to the question why there's an $F$ after $\frac{\Delta F}{\Delta y}$ and not after $\frac{\Delta F}{\Delta t}$, but I guess this has something to do with $y$ being a vector. However, this is not part of the original question anymore.

Comment: @"Are there any such sentences in the book? Did the professor say anything at all while writing those formulas?"
There aren't any explanations in the book and I couldn't attend the lecture (as well as multivariate calculus which might explain the above problem) because I had to do alternative service. Maybe he said something in the lectures, but my fellow students didn't have a clue either.